# Accord .NET, predict claim

Tags: accord.net

I am learning Accord .NET, I have 3 years of claim's data (2016, 2017, 2018)

ie.

```
PYear, Sum_Insured, Claim_Incurred
2016, 1000, 200
2017, 1000, 100
2018, 1000,0
2019, 1000,0
```

what example should I use in order to predict the claim of 2019?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an example this trivial, machine learning is overkill. You can calculate this in your head: the average over all years is 100 or instead the trend indicates -100.

If you want to use Accord just for fun, then simple linear regression will be adequate (you don't need PYear as a feature):

[Linear Regression](http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_Statistics_Models_Regression_Linear_SimpleLinearRegression.htm)